# ZSH Setup on Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, hyperterminal

Hi guys I have various problems with my ZSH shell. I installed Hyper Terminal for Mac and Oh My ZSH with a specific theme.

It works, however I have two problems:

1.) I have no internet connection, due to our corporate proxy. I tried almost everything. export http_proxy=http://my.proxy.dns:8080/ doesn't work and so on.

2.) I don't have the same environment variables as in my standard bash shell. For example when I run 'git' or 'npm' I always get zsh: command not found npm for example.

Now it seems I just need to apply my bash-config to my zsh shell.

I have for example tried setting: `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` inside my .zshrc but no luck. Also source with my bashprofile doesnt seem to work.

How can I do that?